# SQL SERVER - Set variable in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I am performing below update like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET    Field1 = 0       
FROM   MyTable INNER JOIN AnotherTable
       ON MyTable.ID = AnotherTable.ID
WHERE  0=MyFunc(MyTable.ID)
```

MyFunc is a function that returns an int value.

But now I am trying to use the value returned by MyFunc to update another field on table MyTable.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET    Field1 = 0,
       Field2 = CASE WHEN MyFunc(MyTable.ID) = 0 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END
FROM   MyTable INNER JOIN AnotherTable
       ON MyTable.ID = AnotherTable.ID
WHERE  0=MyFunc(MyTable.ID)
```

The problem here is that I am calling twice function MyFunc, one in SET and one in WHERE clause and then I am worried about performance.

I am wondering if there is any other way to do it. I have thought in using a variable, I mean, set this variable in WHERE clause and then use it in the set of the update but I suppose this is not possible, right?

So how can I do this in order to get a better database performance?

Comment: Well... if your WHERE is limiting it to MyFunc=0; what's the point in the case statement?

Comment: *If* `MyFunc` is deterministic, the optimizer may be smart enough to only call it once per row. Before doing anything though - is performance actually an *issue*? Have you set performance *goals*, and is this code not currently meeting them?

Comment: @TZHX Field2 correspondes in my real case to an audit field (a timestamp) so I need to update it or not depending on the value of this function. If MyFunc returns 0 I need to update this field, Field2 (with current timestamp) as well as Field1 (to 0), but if MyFunc returns different from 0 I do not want to update Field2, only Field1.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what your code achieves. First make something that works, before you start to worry over performance.

Comment: @TZHX Above code works, but this is not my real case, I have posted here an example, using a string instead of a timestamp, but the idea is the same I think.

Comment: You say it works, but it doesn't do what you claim you want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` to simulate a variable. The following `SELECT` will be able to address the function's result with the *variable name* `FuncResult`.

```
SELECT MyTable.Field1 
      ,MyTable.Field2
      ,x.FuncResult
FROM  MyTable 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT dbo.MyFunc(MyTable.ID) AS FuncResult) AS x
INNER JOIN AnotherTable
       ON MyTable.ID = AnotherTable.ID
WHERE FuncResult=0
```

Furthermore you might check an updateable CTE like here:

```
WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT MyTable.Field1 
          ,MyTable.Field2
          ,x.FuncResult
    FROM  MyTable 
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT dbo.MyFunc(MyTable.ID) AS FuncResult) AS x
    INNER JOIN AnotherTable
           ON MyTable.ID = AnotherTable.ID
    WHERE FuncResult=0
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE
SET Field1=0
   ,Field2=CASE WHEN FuncResult = 0 /*senseless, as your where clause filters to only this value!*/ THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NOK' END
```

But - to be honest - the whole question looks like *starting to build a house on the second floor*... I'm pretty sure, that the engine is smart enough to chash a function's result and reuse it with the same input (at least *per row*).

And if you really bother about performance **avoid scalar functions**. If you need a function here, an ***inline** table valued function*, which may return just on column in one row, is much faster.

### UPDATE

Here an example for an `INLINED tabe value function` (single-statement, *ad-hoc*, no `BEGIN...END`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TestInlineTVF(@input INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT @input*2 AS FuncResult;
GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Row 1'),('Row 2');

SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY dbo.TestInlineTVF(t.ID) AS x
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.TestInlineTVF;
```

Comment: what you say at the end using an inline table valued function seems interesting so could you provide an example of it? I am not expert in databases, so very sorry.